# Why do we have a minion and minionpro tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

On the main site there are two tags: [minion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minion) and [minionpro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minionpro). Both tags seem to cover identical material. Should they be synonyms or did I miss some details?

Comment: Well `minionpro` is a packge, and Minion is a font. But in the context of the site it seems most likely that they should be treated as synonyms (with minionpro being the main tag I should think.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Ah, okay, didn't catch the difference by looking at the questions. I'd also use `minionpro` as the main tag.

Comment: The tricky part is that people using XeTeX and LuaTeX can use the Minion Pro fonts without further support (except for math). What `minionpro` does is add math support and allows the font to be used with pdfTeX. But having a tag for a particular font seems unusual, which is why they are probably reasonable synonyms.

Comment: Neither tag wikis point to the other.

Comment: @MartinSchröder But both tag wikis mention the Minion Pro font as point of concern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion they should not be synonyms but the [minion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minion) tag should be removed and questions retagged to [minionpro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minionpro) or [fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fontspec).

---

**UPDATE:**  I have retagged all questions in [minion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minion) and [myriad](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myriad) (which I stumbled upon) and [pinged the moderators](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39418842#39418842) to remove the tags.

---

It doesn't make sense to have tags for different font faces because there are infinitely many.  At the same time we do not have a [palatino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palatino) tag even though this is one of the most popular non-standard fonts for LaTeX documents (used, e.g., in `classicthesis` and the `memoir` docs).  Usually font questions revolve around how to use them in LaTeX which is font independent in the case of OpenType fonts and package dependent for Type1 fonts for which there are package tags (e.g. [times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/times), [eulervm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eulervm), etc.).

However, I do not want to generalize the statement about font tags to [computer-modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-modern) and [latin-modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-modern).  These still deserve special treatment as they are the standard fonts which most users are confronted with on a daily basis.  Therefore I consider them to belong to the circle of [TeX and friends](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7371).

Comment: Nice answer. I totally agree. Who can vote for tag deletion?

Comment: @TeXnician ... mm I should have omitted calling you out...but this question is not about `palatino`, nor it's about `times`, much less about `computer-modern` or `latin-modern` fonts. I guess I don't make sense so let's retag every thing... So my dear Henri, what exactly is your proposal with `myriad` then?

Comment: @doed I laid out why tags for specific fonts (other than the standard fonts) do not make sense.  That is why I retagged everything in {minion} to either {minionpro} (if the question is about pdfLaTeX, which uses these support files) or {fontspec} (if the question uses the OpenType fonts).  For {myriad} a tag {myriadpro} does not exist, so I just removed it from all.